# Spring Security : Add custom message for authentication failure ( "Bad Credentials" to "Invalid Credentials")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        loginRequest.getUserName(),
        loginRequest.getPassword()
    )
);
```

Currently the response is like below:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-30T17:50:38.307+0000",
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "details": "uri=/auth"
}
```

I want this to be like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-30T17:50:38.307+0000",
  "message": "Invalid credentials",
  "details": "uri=/auth"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security uses the *messages.properties* which consist of default messages, we can add our custom message with the same. Add *messages.properties* and add a message as shown below.

**messages.properties**

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid credentials
```

[**Defaults**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/messages.properties)

```
AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied=Access is denied
AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.emptyPassword=Empty Password
AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticationNotFound=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Bad credentials
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired=User credentials have expired
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled=User is disabled
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired=User account has expired
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked=User account is locked
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports=Only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is supported
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.credentialsExpired=User credentials have expired
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.disabled=User is disabled
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.expired=User account has expired
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.locked=User account is locked
AclEntryAfterInvocationProvider.noPermission=Authentication {0} has NO permissions to the domain object {1}
AnonymousAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=The presented AnonymousAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key
BindAuthenticator.badCredentials=Bad credentials
BindAuthenticator.emptyPassword=Empty Password
CasAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=The presented CasAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key
CasAuthenticationProvider.noServiceTicket=Failed to provide a CAS service ticket to validate
ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed=Maximum sessions of {0} for this principal exceeded
DigestAuthenticationFilter.incorrectRealm=Response realm name {0} does not match system realm name of {1}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.incorrectResponse=Incorrect response
DigestAuthenticationFilter.missingAuth=Missing mandatory digest value for 'auth' QOP; received header {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.missingMandatory=Missing mandatory digest value; received header {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceCompromised=Nonce token compromised {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceEncoding=Nonce is not encoded in Base64; received nonce {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceExpired=Nonce has expired/timed out
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceNotNumeric=Nonce token should have yielded a numeric first token, but was {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceNotTwoTokens=Nonce should have yielded two tokens but was {0}
DigestAuthenticationFilter.usernameNotFound=Username {0} not found
JdbcDaoImpl.noAuthority=User {0} has no GrantedAuthority
JdbcDaoImpl.notFound=User {0} not found
LdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Bad credentials
LdapAuthenticationProvider.badLdapConnection=Connection to LDAP server failed
LdapAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired=User credentials have expired
LdapAuthenticationProvider.disabled=User is disabled
LdapAuthenticationProvider.expired=User account has expired
LdapAuthenticationProvider.locked=User account is locked
LdapAuthenticationProvider.emptyUsername=Empty username not allowed
LdapAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports=Only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is supported
PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.badCredentials=Bad credentials
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.cookieStolen=Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
ProviderManager.providerNotFound=No AuthenticationProvider found for {0}
RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=The presented RememberMeAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key
RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=The presented RunAsUserToken does not contain the expected key
SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor.noMatching=No matching pattern was found in subjectDN: {0}
SwitchUserFilter.noCurrentUser=No current user associated with this request
SwitchUserFilter.noOriginalAuthentication=Could not find original Authentication object
```